# update a field value in a form using libcurl

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

My situation is following:

First time the form looks like below:

first = yes
fileupload = file

since after the first time, I'd like to change 
first = no

But when I do like below it keeps adding first = yes no no no no.....

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "first", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "yes",
CURLFORM_END)
```

==>

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "first", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "no",
CURLFORM_END)
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Semantics of curl_formadd is to add a section to a multipart/formdata HTTP POST. Every time this API is invoke lastptr is updated to point to the end of the form. And subsequent invocation appends the data to it.

I am afraid you need to start the form all over again to set it to new value. You may want to use curl_formfree()  to cleanup your form before rebuilding.